# Split cell data into individual rows when multiple fields are separated by comma

Tags: excel, vba

I have following data in single cell in excel, I want to add new rows and split this comma separated data on individual lines. I tried using function 'dependentArray = Split(dependentIDs, ", " & vbCrLf)' but it is not working. kindly help me with the right code.

sample data,

```
"F101462 - Receive and apply Early Pay payments/AutoPay,
F118248 - Integration Testing - Payments Flow,
F118248 - Integration Testing - Payments Integration with Maestro"
```

I using function dependentArray = Split(dependentIDs, ", " ) but then this splits everything where there is a comma, even if there is a comma in feature name it will split it.

Comment: Why use a comma delimiter if your strings are allowed to contain such delimiter, wouldn't it be better to use another delimiter (i.e. a semi-colon ";")? Also, do your ids always start with an "F" and have 7 characters?

Comment: Line break inside a cell is typically `vbLf`, so maybe try `Split(dependentIDs, ", " & vbLf)`

Comment: Where do you see the trailing (or even leading) space? It should be `"," & vbLf`.

Answer (score 0):

split by " , F" and join the results with an F at start?

Comment: This wouldn't be an optimal solution, there is a chance that undesired splits occur as there is a possibility that the char followed by ", " is an F.

Comment: ok here is another one for you then.
I see that the delimeter is the break line character, chr(10) in vba.
you can just 
1. select the cell
2. CTRL+H to open replace window
3. in find what press CTRL+J which is the equivalent of Alt+enter in cell aka chr(10)
4. in replace with enter something unique like -------------
5. use text split with the new delimiter now and you are set.

Comment: That would not do because there is a possibility of getting , F in feature name itself.

Answer (score 0):

- The row delimiter in a cell is Chr(10)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Replace function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008930)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim sTxt As String, aTxt
    sTxt = Range("A1")
    sTxt = Replace(sTxt, Chr(34), "")
    If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then
        aTxt = Split(sTxt, Chr(10))
        Range("A5").Resize(UBound(aTxt) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(aTxt)
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]